# HTML5 Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms, html, validation, css

I have two major problem regarding HTML5 form validation.

**1-** I use this code to change the validation message of inputs

```
$$('INPUT').each(function(input) 
{    
  input.oninvalid = function(event) 
  {
     event.target.setCustomValidity('');
     if (!event.target.validity.valid) event.target.setCustomValidity('Please Fill');
  };
}
```

There's a big problem with this method. As the form is submitted if the input is invalid, an error message is attached to it. So **it wouldn't validate on new input**. Even after correction and submitting again it won't let the form get submitted because the message is still attached. so event.target.setCustomValidity('') will remove the message and form needs another submit. **two submit after correction.**

I couldn't find a way to correct this behavior.

**2-How can I hide or disable these tooltips totally but still use form validation. Sometimes I want to use css invalid and valid pseudo classes, but these tips are still displayed.**

I find **formnovalidate** on submit button and then I can check **validity.valid** of each inputs manually before submitting. any better idea?

Comment: Why not clear the "custom validity" flags on the next "change" event (or even "keyup" or any other interaction)?

Comment: Handling the results of using  the "setCustomValidity()" API.  If you clear the string as soon as the user starts interacting with the form, you would avoid the double-submit problem.

Comment: I will test it. Do you know any good resource about HTML5 Validation. I found some, but most of them are general.

Comment: The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) page is pretty good. It's a simple system, which I think is partly what makes it confusing.

Comment: Can you put your code in a jsFiddle.  [This example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/cPRpg/) is doing essentially the same thing as your code, but it doesn't require double submission.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of question 1:

I had an input

```
<input name="VoucherCode"  id="VoucherCode"  type="text" pattern="(1[0-9]{9})|(2[0-9]{9})" value="">
```

And improved the default message

```
$("#VoucherCode").on("invalid", function (event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('The format of Voucher Code is not correct.')
});
```

But this had the same problem you encountered: if the user gets the first attempt wrong, a correct response still show the invalid pattern message.

I fixed this based on @Pointy's suggestion:

```
$("#VoucherCode").on("invalid", function (event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('The format of Voucher Code is not correct.')
}).bind('blur', function (event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('');                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

(a bit late) but the solution could be around there!

What happen:
Since you customize the error message `event.target.setCustomValidity("...")` the property in the `element.validity.customError` is `true` ; the [reportValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) with always return `false` and the submit wouldn't be valid

What I did?
When the User change the input (`event.on Change`) - I set up back the default error message `event.target.setCustomValidity('');` this will tells the Browser to keep working without a custom error